# Calculate area under curve $(y+1)^2 x=1$ in first quadrant

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, area

$$(y+1)^2 x=1$$

We have to calculate area under this curve, bounded by ordinate and abscissa in first quadrant. Task also says that we have to express area as improper integral and then calculate it.

This is what i got so far.

$y=\sqrt{\frac1{x}}-1$

I think area is given by $$\int_{0\leftarrow}^{+\infty} \left ( \sqrt{\frac1{x}}-1\right )dx=\int_{0\leftarrow}^{+\infty}x^{-\frac1{2}}dx\quad -\int_{0\leftarrow}^{+\infty}dx$$

I get some weird stuff when solving this integrals, so do you think I am on right path?

Answer (score 3):

The graph meets the $x$-axis at $x=1$, after which the curve remains below the $x$-axis. So, integrating your expression from $0$ to $1$ is sufficient.

$$\text{Area}=\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-1\right)dx$$

Comment: $$\int_{0\leftarrow}^{1} \left ( \sqrt{\frac1{x}}-1\right )dx$$ Do i have to write arrow at zero

Comment: @RushO'Brien If your instructor requires it, do. But it's not a widely used notation, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could view $x$ as a function of $y$ and hence write $x = \frac{1}{(y+1)^2}$. Now consider the integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(y+1)^2} \, dy$.

Answer (score 0):

Your upper limit of integration seems to be incorrect as the function cuts x axis at 1